# Rally SDK App using Grid with collapsible tree of children stories

Tags: rally, appsdk2

Is it possible, and how would one create a grid-like app that with specified columns but also shows children stories nested under their parent stories the way a Portfolio Hierarchy shows them?

As far as I can tell, the Portfolio Hierarchy view doesn't allow additional columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a grid of user stories where the stories are nested under features, and collapsible. The deployment html is in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/stories-grouped-by-feature).

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        var today = new Date().toISOString();
        Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                model: 'UserStory',
                fetch: ['ObjectID', 'FormattedID', 'Name', 'ScheduleState', 'Feature'],
                autoLoad: true,
                filters: [
                    {
                        property: 'Iteration.StartDate',
                        operator: '<=',
                        value: today
                    },
                    {
                        property: 'Iteration.EndDate',
                        operator: '>=',
                        value: today
                    },
                    {
                        property: 'Feature',
                        operator: '!=',
                        value: null
                    }
                ],
                listeners: {
                    load: this._onDataLoaded,
                    scope: this
                }
                });
    },
    _onDataLoaded: function(store, records){
        var that = this;
        var promises = [];
         _.each(records, function(story) {
            promises.push(that._getFeature(story, that));
        });

        Deft.Promise.all(promises).then({
            success: function(results) {
                that._stories = results;
                that._makeGrid();
            }
        });
    },

    _getFeature: function(story, scope) {
        var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
        var that = scope;
            var featureOid = story.get('Feature').ObjectID;
            Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
            scope: this,
            success: function(model, operation) {
                fetch: ['State'],
                model.load(featureOid, {
                    scope: this,
                    success: function(record, operation) {
                        var featureState = record.get('State')._refObjectName;
                        var storyRef = story.get('_ref');
                        var storyOid  = story.get('ObjectID');
                        var storyFid = story.get('FormattedID');
                        var storyName  = story.get('Name');
                        var storyState = story.get('ScheduleState');
                        var feature = story.get('Feature');

                        result = {
                                    "_ref"          : storyRef,
                                    "ObjectID"      : storyOid,
                                    "FormattedID"   : storyFid,
                                    "Name"          : storyName,
                                    "ScheduleState" : storyState,
                                    "Feature"       : feature,
                                    "FeatureState"  : featureState,
                                    "FeatureID"     : featureOid   
                                };
                        deferred.resolve(result);    
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return deferred; 
    },

    _makeGrid: function() {
        var that = this;

        if (that._grid) {
            that._grid.destroy();
        }

        var gridStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
            data: that._stories,
            groupField: 'FeatureID',
            pageSize: 1000,
        });

        that._grid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            itemId: 'storyGrid',
            store: gridStore,
            features: [{ftype:'grouping'}],
            columnCfgs: [
                {
                    text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                },

                {
                    text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', 
                },
                {
                    text: 'ScheduleState', dataIndex: 'ScheduleState', 
                },
                {
                    text: 'Feature', dataIndex: 'Feature',
                    renderer: function(val, meta, record) {
                        return '<a href="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/detail/portfolioitem/feature/' + record.get('Feature').ObjectID + '" target="_blank">' + record.get('Feature').FormattedID + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Feature State', dataIndex: 'FeatureState',
                }
            ]
        });

        that.add(that._grid);
        that._grid.reconfigure(gridStore);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks nickm,  I'm still trying to verify that this solution works for my question.  I'd like to ask another question based on the code you show above but I'll ask as another question to keep it separate.